# How does wing sweep impact lift?

Tags: aircraft-design, lift, wing-sweep

Given that swept wings (according to a google search) decrease lift, how much is lift affected? Why are they so commonly used in aircraft nowadays, like the SU-27, and subsonic aircraft like the Boeing 787?

Comment: There are already [many answers](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=Swept+wing) about this topic (pros, cons, stability, drag, swept forward and backward, ...). If you feel like none answers your doubt maybe you can post a more specific question.